# Sublimeの行折返し機能における半角全角対応

Tags: sublimetext, key-binding

お世話になります．

SublimeでEmacs Pro Essentialsパッケージを使っています．Alt-Qを押すと所
定文字数での行の折り返しを行う機能(wrap-line)がありますが，文字数カウ
ントにおいて半角全角の区別がありません．

例えば折り返し文字数を80文字と設定した場合に，半角だけなら80文字，全角
だけなら40文字(各文字を2文字分としてカウント)，というようにしたいので
すが，実現する方法(設定方法・拡張パッケージ等)はありますでしょうか．

Comment: 私は Sublime Text を使っていないのですが、検索してみるとエディタ自身の issue として「CJK文字が適切に折り返しされない」というのが残っているのを見つけました。もしかすると未解決かつ既知の問題なのかもしれません。リンク: [\[CJK\] Handle wrapping properly about Chinese and Japanese](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/606)

Comment: コメントくださいまして，どうもありがとうございます！Sublimeではサポートできてないようですね．本家Stack Overflowにて修正すべきモジュール個所を教えていただきました(下記URL)．ちゃんと内容をまだ読んでおりませんが，Pythonで書かれたルーチンなので比較的簡単に修正できるように思いました．修正できるかやってみようと思っております．
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093610/how-to-make-sublime-wrap-line-support-half-width-and-full-width-characters